# Where can I find info about the Windows registry?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry

Where can I find info about the Windows registry, e.g. what the info in `HKLM_USERS` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) is a good point to start with. Check [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256986) of Microsoft as well (Windows registry information for advanced users).